# Index page not showing after adding database to Flask app

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm creating an app after creating the database model. It has not given any error but after adding the `db.commit()` in `index` route it is not showing the index page but showing other pages without any error. I've provided links to the error images. I'm not getting what I did wrong.

`app.py` ->

```
from flask import Flask , render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import datetime as dt
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

#app config
app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY']="ASGH}|#%*9"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']="sqlite:///site.db"

#db
db=SQLAlchemy(app)
ma=Marshmallow(app)

#model
class contact(db.Model):
    id= db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key="True")
    name= db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    mobile= db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email= db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False)
    company_name= db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    subject= db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False)
    message= db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date_posted= db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=dt.datetime.now())

class ContactSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields=("id","name","mobile","email","company_name","subject","message","date_posted")

 cnt_schema= ContactSchema()
 cnts_schema= ContactSchema(many=True)

 #pages
 @app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def index():
     if request.method == "POST":
         name= request.form.get("Name")
         mobile= request.form.get("mobile")
         email= request.form.get("email")
         cmp_nm= request.form.get("c_name")
         sub= request.form.get("subject")
         msg= request.form.get("msg")
   
         #storing into db
         cnt= contact(name,mobile,email,cmp_nm,sub,msg)
         db.session.add(cnt)
         db.session.commit()
         #alter box required
   return render_template("index.html")
```

`templates/index.html` ->

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block title %} {% endblock %}
{% block body %}

<div class="container md:mx-auto">
<h3>Contact</h3>
<div class="row">
    <form class="col s12" action="{{ url_for("app")}}" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
        <input id="icon_prefix" name="Name" type="text" class="validate">
        <label for="icon_prefix">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
        <input id="icon_telephone" name="mobile" type="tel" class="validate">
        <label for="icon_telephone">Telephone</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
        <input id="icon_email" name="email" type="tel" class="validate">
        <label for="icon_email">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">business</i>
        <input id="icon_business" name="c_name" type="tel" class="validate">
        <label for="icon_business">Company Name</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
        <input id="icon_prefix2" name="subject" type="text" class="validate">
        <label for="icon_prefix2">Subject</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">keyboard</i>
        <textarea id="textarea1" name="msg" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
        <label for="icon_keyboard">Message</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
    </button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

After adding database this is the exception I'm getting: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja4vZ.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2yA7.png).

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Please post error messages as text, not as images.

Comment: werkzeug.routing.BuildError

werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'app'. Did you mean 'about' instead?
Traceback (most recent call last)

    File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__

    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

    File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app

    response = self.handle_exception(e)

Comment: it's too long text so I added images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `templates/index.html` you made a mistake:

```
<form class="col s12" action="{{ url_for("app")}}" method="post">
```

should be :

```
<form class="col s12" action="{{ url_for("index")}}" method="post">
```

Comment: I've made changes but after pressing submit button it again show error

Comment: Is it the same error ?

Comment: The error message " __init__ takes only 1 argument but 7 are given.